# Error during copying stream in c++ using the rdbuf() and operator <<

Tags: c++, filestream

The "standard" offered way to copy files, for example through c++ is.

```
ifstream ins;
ofstream out s;
// I've omitted the opening of those stream, since it is not important for the following question.

s << ins.rdbuf();
```

Now, the problem is that the above line may fail, and in some cases, especially the one I'll talk about, there is no way I found to know that something went wrong.

Assume the input stream is actually a large file sitting on remote NAS machine, for example.
Now, there may be connetion errors which will cause the file handle to be invalid.
Trying to simulate this, I used a large file, in debugger I stopped on this line, found the handle, then continued the debugger and then closed the file handle forcibly (through process-explorer of the sysinternals suite).

The result is: the line finished, the file is not being copied correctly, sometimes it is not copied at all, sometimes only part of the file is being closed.
In contradiction to the documentation of the operator<<, and the rdbuf(), there is no setting of bad/fail state, and no exception is being thrown.

The only thing I could notice, is that when trying to close the input-stream, an exception is being raised.

Did anyone so the same phenomenon ?! 
Is there anyway to check/test this for correct completion ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Streams are notoriously bad with regards to error reporting.  In this
case, all you can do is check for `badbit` on the output stream; the
standard requires the `<<` operators to absorb all exceptions, setting
the `badbit` if they occur.  And obviously, this doesn't tell you
whether the error was due to an error on input or an error on output.

Typically, if you're using the implementations which come with most 
compilers, there won't be an error reported on input anyway.  For the
most part, unless things have changed in recent years, implementations
of `filebuf` treat errors on input exactly like end of file.

If you need better error reporting, I think you're stuck with
implementing your own `streambuf` (not really very difficult), which
keeps track of the various errors; you can then ask the `streambuf`
after the transfer what errors it received.

Comment: "_treat errors on input exactly like end of file_" is that cfront iostream legacy?

Comment: @curiousguy I suspect that it goes back further than that.  It was more or less standard practice for most programs I've seen using `FILE*` as well.  (This is for input.  For output, careful programs do check after close that no error has occurred.)

Comment: In the old time, was there even a way for a stream buffer to indicate read failure, as opposed to EOF?

Comment: @curiousguy No.  The only way a `streambuf` can report an error on input is with an exception.  In the old days, there weren't exceptions.

Comment: @curiousguy Not that I know of.  I don't see how it could be: the **only** possibility the `streambuf` had to report anything was to return `EOF` instead of a character.  (Note that the `streambuf` interface for input is largely based on the prevailing practice of character input with `FILE*`: `getc` until it returned `EOF`, and consider that end of file.)

Comment: I think I get it: stdio returns EOF when a read returns no data, then you use `feof` and `ferror`. The `streambuf` abstraction kept the EOF convention. OTOH, the `streambuf` abstraction does not provides these diagnostic eof/error functions.

Comment: @curiousguy You can certainly use `feof` and `ferror` in standard C.  I'm not sure that they were there in pre-standard, and I've certainly never seen a program which used them.  And before switching to C++, I saw a lot of C code, including many of the Unix utilities.  I'm not sure anly longer as to what one could do, but I have a pretty good idea about what people did do.  The original `istream` was designed to support what people did do, and no more.  (Regrettably)